# AttributeError: 'module' object as no attribute '_Application'

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, comtypes

At end of my program, I am generating word file then converting this file to .pdf file format as the following:

```
wdFormatPDF = 17
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(resultfile)
doc.SaveAs(resultfilepdf, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

The program run properly but when I converting the

.py to .exe using pyinstaller –onefile option I get the following error when executing the .exe file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\tub\test\hc.py", line 344, in <module>
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
  File "C:\Users\LT440\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\LT440\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\LT440\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 112, in GetBestInterface
interface = getattr(mod, itf_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Application'
[4112] Failed to execute script hc
```

Please advice.

Comment: so what is the ```Word.Application``` object ?

Comment: Regarding comtypes.client module __ini__.py file
'progid' may be a string like "Excel.Application",
you can find more information as the following [link](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/master/comtypes/client/__init__.py)

Comment: I experienced the same problem while converting my .doc files to pdf. Then I used win32com which worked fine (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056793/python-win32com-client-dispatch-looping-through-word-documents-and-export-to-pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

I have same。I solved it
Clear Gen's cache! I am deleting all the caches in this directory. The conversion is normal!
*..\Python3.6\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen*