# Comtypes has no attribute '_Application'

Tags: python, ms-office, file-conversion, comtypes

I'm experiencing a weird bug in a file conversion script I wrote in python.  I'm using the comtypes library to convert different types of files into pdfs and for some reason, I get `module 'comtypes.gen.Excel' has no attribute '_Application'` whenever I try to create a client object for an excel application.  I can't seem to find anything online specific to this issue.  The script was working fine about a month or two ago, so I'm confused as to why it isn't working anymore - the only thing I could think of was excel updating or something (if that would even matter).  I have the office 2016 if that's relevant.  If anyone has experienced this bug or has any ideas, help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the script, for reference:

```
import comtypes.client

excel = comtypes.client.CreateObject("Excel.Application") # exception here
excel.Visible = False
in_file = "INPUT_FILE"
out_file = "OUT_FILE"
f = excel.Workbooks.Open(in_file)
f.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, out_file, 1, 0)
f.Close()
excel.Close()
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986806/attributeerror-module-object-as-no-attribute-application) post can help?

Comment: The suggestion there didn't work for me, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, did you found something? I've tried to run the add as adm already.

Comment: Same here, would love a solution

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using comtypes.client
Use pywin32

```
import win32com.client
#Replace excel=comtype.client.blablabla to
excel=win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
```

Keep remaining things as it is.

Ref. https://github.com/shardulind/pdfconv_python/blob/master/convertor.py