# AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.Word' has no attribute '_Application' when trying to convert .docx to .pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Basically I created a GUI that when I click a button it allows me to choose a .docx file and turn it into a .pdf and save it to my desktop. Here is the code I have so far but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/X/OneDrive/Desktop/X/X/software.py", line 26, in select_file
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 250, in CreateObject
    return _manage(obj, clsid, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 188, in _manage
    obj = GetBestInterface(obj)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 112, in GetBestInterface
    interface = getattr(mod, itf_name)
AttributeError: module 'comtypes.gen.Word' has no attribute '_Application'
```

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
window.title("Hi")

label1 = Label(window, text="Hi", font=("arial", 16, "bold")).pack()


# start of select file button
def select_file():
    window.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                               filetypes=(("word documents", "*.docx"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    print(window.filename)
    print("work")

    wdFormatPDF = 17

    in_file = window.filename
    out_file = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
    doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()


b = Button(window, text="Test", command=select_file)
b.pack()
# end of select file button

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comtypes has no attribute '\_Application'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825798/comtypes-has-no-attribute-application)

Comment: This question [attributeerror-module-object-as-no-attribute-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48986806/attributeerror-module-object-as-no-attribute-application) may help.