# .xlsx and xls(Latest Versions) to pdf using python

Tags: python, excel, pdf, excel-2010, win32com

With the help of this [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)
Link I am trying for excel (.xlsx and xls formats)

**Following is modified Code for Excel:**

```
import os
from win32com import client

folder = "C:\\Oprance\\Excel\\XlsxWriter-0.5.1"
file_type = 'xlsx'
out_folder = folder + "\\PDF_excel"

os.chdir(folder)

if not os.path.exists(out_folder):
    print 'Creating output folder...'
    os.makedirs(out_folder)
    print out_folder, 'created.'
else:
    print out_folder, 'already exists.\n'

for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print files

print '\n\n'

word = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".xlsx") or files.endswith('xls'):
        out_name = files.replace(file_type, r"pdf")
        in_file = os.path.abspath(folder + "\\" + files)
        out_file = os.path.abspath(out_folder + "\\" + out_name)
        doc = word.Workbooks.Open(in_file)
        print 'Exporting', out_file
        doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=56)
        doc.Close()
```

**It is showing following error :**

```
>>> execfile('excel_to_pdf.py')
Creating output folder...
C:\Excel\XlsxWriter-0.5.1\PDF_excel created.
apms_trial.xlsx
~$apms_trial.xlsx

Exporting C:\Excel\XlsxWriter-0.5.1\PDF_excel\apms_trial.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "excel_to_pdf.py", line 30, in <module>
    doc = word.Workbooks.Open(in_file)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 8, in Open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel
', u"Excel cannot open the file '~$apms_trial.xlsx' because the file format or f
ile extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that
 the file extension matches the format of the file.", u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -21468
27284), None)
>>>
```

There is problem in

**doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=56)**

What should be **FileFormat** file format?
Please Help

Comment: Maybe you have VisualBasic objects or weird relations in that Excel file? You can confirm that by saving a new clean (empty) Excel file and trying to open that one. If that goes well, then there's something wrong with the current file. Also, in what Excel version are you saving? That library will probably work better in 97/2004 format than in the very latest Excel versions.

Comment: @Allendar :What can I do for Latest versions or greater than 2004 for excel versions

Comment: Did you already test if the previous versions work? To make newer versions work you have to do research on that library. Maybe you need an alternative (newer) library to get support for later versions. But I can't really confirm any of that. Only thing you can do is research what is possible. If there's really no solution in Python, you can always see if there are maybe command line tools for Excel or Ruby/PHP/Perl scripts that you could then call from the shell.

Comment: @Allendar : I tried for 97 - 2003 version but it is not saving in pdf form for them is is saving xls form only. For Word Document there is no problem but for excel is the problem. Thank you I will do more Research on this.

Comment: http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/09/cant-save-excel-2010-files-as-pdf-using-pythons-win32com-api/ Got this link. But there must be some solution to do this in python

Comment: Actually, based on the error message, I think the problem is that you're finding the temp file created by Excel, which starts with a `~$`. When you try and convert the temp file, it complains. Try closing Excel if you have it open, or deleting that file, or ignoring it with an `if` statement.

Comment: You also have a bug on this line: `out_name = files.replace(file_type, r"pdf")` because you never replace file type `xls` with `pdf`, you only replace `xlsx`, so if you ever try to convert an `xls` file it will overwrite the existing.

Comment: The file starting with ~$ is a temp file. Your line should be like `if ((files.endswith(".xlsx") or files.endswith('xls')) and files[0] != "~"):`

Answer (score 23):

Link of xlsxwriter :

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contents.html

With the help of this you can generate excel file with **.xlsx** and **.xls**

for example excel file generated name is **trial.xls**

**Now if you want to generate pdf of that excel file then do the following :**

```
from win32com import client
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\excel\\trial.xls')
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'C:\\excel\\trial.pdf')
```

Comment: While xlsxwriter is a useful tool, it unfortunately doesn't enable you to edit an existing xls file, only to create one from scratch. This renders it useless in many cases.

Comment: Is this a windows only solution?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same thing and the same error... ANSWER: 57.... see below...

```
from win32com import client
import win32api

def exceltopdf(doc):
    excel = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    excel.Visible = 0

    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(doc)
    ws = wb.Worksheets[1]

    try:
        wb.SaveAs('c:\\targetfolder\\result.pdf', FileFormat=57)
    except Exception, e:
        print "Failed to convert"
        print str(e)
    finally:
        wb.Close()
        excel.Quit()
```

... as an alternative to the fragile ExportAsFixedFormat...

Answer (score 1):

You can print an excel sheet to pdf on linux using python.
Do need to run openoffice as a headless server and use unoconv, takes a bit of configuring but is doable

You run OO as a (service) daemon and use it for the conversions for xls, xlsx and doc, docx.

http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for

Is to start gotenberg docker container locally

https://github.com/gotenberg/gotenberg

And pass (any supported by libreoffice) file from python wia HTTP to the container and get result as pdf

```
LIBREOFFICE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/forms/libreoffice/convert'
LIBREOFFICE_LANDSCAPE_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/forms/libreoffice/convert?landscape=1'


def _retry_gotenberg(url, io_bytes, post_file_name='index.html'):
    response = None
    for _ in range(5):
        response = requests.post(url, files={post_file_name: io_bytes})
        if response.status_code == 200:
            break
        logging.info('Will sleep and retry: %s %s', response.status_code, response.content)
        sleep(3)
    if not response or response.status_code != 200:
        raise RuntimeRrror(f'Bad response from doc-to-pdf: {response.status_code} {response.content}')
    return response

def process_libreoffice(io_bytes, ext: str):
    if ext in ('.doc', '.docx'):
        url = LIBREOFFICE_URL
    else:
        url = LIBREOFFICE_LANDSCAPE_URL
    response = self._retry_gotenberg(url, io_bytes, post_file_name=f'file.{ext}')
    return response.content
```

Answer (score 0):

The [GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.groupdocs.cloud/conversion/python) is another option to convert Excel to PDF. It is paid API. However, it provides 150 free monthly API calls.

P.S: I'm a developer evangelist at GroupDocs.

```
# Import module
import groupdocs_conversion_cloud
from shutil import copyfile

# Get your client_id and client_key at https://dashboard.groupdocs.cloud (free registration is required).
client_id = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
client_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Create instance of the API
convert_api = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertApi.from_keys(client_id, client_key)

try:

        #Convert PDF to PNG
        # Prepare request
        request = groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ConvertDocumentDirectRequest("pdf", "C:/Temp/Book1.xlsx")

        # Convert
        result = convert_api.convert_document_direct(request)       
        copyfile(result, 'C:/Temp/Book1_output.pdf')
        print("Result {}".format(result))
        
except groupdocs_conversion_cloud.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling get_supported_conversion_types: {0}".format(e.message))
```