# How to convert xlsx (containing both data and image) to PDF in MacOs?

Tags: python, excel, macos, pdf

I have an Excel file with both data and image like charts. I want to convert this xslx file to PDF in Python in Mac. I am able to convert the Excel file with only data to PDF but when the Excel contains image also along with data then I don't find any solution for this.

Comment: When you tried to convert excel with an image, What is the output you are getting means getting any exception? Write here your functionality and output logs also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.xlsx and xls(Latest Versions) to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854840/xlsx-and-xlslatest-versions-to-pdf-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using https://www.pyxll.com/ and just starting the regular print as pdf function?

Comment: I am using mac Franksta and pyxll will not support macOS right.

Comment: Would it be an option to create a macro for the printing in VBA and just starting it through python?