# How to convert excel sheets into PDF using Python without breaking worksheets content?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsx, xls

I want to convert .xls/.xlsx files with into pdf file. I have tried libreoffice, soffice, unoconv, utility in python but its breaking the context of worksheet after pdf conversion if the worksheet having more than 20 columns.

Also tried excel2image, but seems like its having some dependency of pywin32 of windows i.e. not supporing in linux.

Any help will really appreciate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326782/python-converting-xlsx-to-pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Converting XLSX to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326782/python-converting-xlsx-to-pdf)