# Converting xls to pdf

Tags: python, excel, email

I'm trying to execute a script to convert a XLS file to a PDF file:

```
from win32com import client
import win32api


input_file = r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking\25063599.xls"
#give your file name with valid path
output_file = r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\attachments\75090058\Status\Verwerking\test.pdf"
#give valid output file name and path
app = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
app.Interactive = False
app.Visible = False
Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
try:
    Workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to convert in PDF format.Please confirm environment meets all the requirements  and try again")
    print(str(e))
finally:
    Workbook.Close()
    app.Exit()
```

However, getting the following error:

```
File "xls.py", line 9, in <module>
    app = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 113, in DispatchEx
    dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, None, clsctx, serverInfo, (pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,))[0]
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024894, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, None)
```

I've closed Excel.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem caused by the fact, that the referenced COM-Interface cannot be found. Normally you have to make sure, that the referenced Office-Tools are installed correctly or that the reference OCS-module is registered correctly.

Maybe you could try to use the pandas lib instead of COM? See [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52326782/python-converting-xlsx-to-pdf)