# How to improve the HTML Table Styling that is to be converted into a PDF File

Tags: html, css, html-table, jinja2, pdfkit

I have a Python code that is creating HTML Tables and then turning it into a PDF file. This is the output that I am currently getting

[image: At 55% Zoom]

This image is taken from PDF File that is being generated as result (and it is zoomed out at 55%)

I want to make this look better. Something similar to this, if I may

[image]

*This image has 13 columns, I don't want that. I want to keep 5 columns* but my major concern is the size of the `td` in my HTML files. It is too small in `width` and that is why, the text is also very stacked up in each `td`. But if you look at the other image, text is much more visible and boxes are much more bigger width wise. Moreover, it doesn't suffer from height problems either (the height of the box is in such a way that it covers the whole of the PDF Page and all the `tds` don't look like `stretched down`)

I have tried to play around the height and width of my `td` in the HTML File, but unfortunately, nothing really seemed to work for me.

**Edit**: Using the code provided by `onkar ruikar`, I was able to achieve very good results. However, it created the same problem that I was facing previously. The question was asked here: [Horizontally merge and divide cells in an HTML Table for Timetable based on the Data in Python File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623210/horizontally-merge-and-divide-cells-in-an-html-table-for-timetable-based-on-the)

I changed up the `template.html` file of mine and then ran the same code. But I got this result,

[image]

As you can see, that there were more than one lectures in the First Slot of Monday, and due to that, it overlapped both the courses. It is not reading the `<hr>` command properly in this HTML file now.

The modified `template.html` file has this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<header>
  <style>
  .new-page {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
.center
{
  text-align: center;

}
.left
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 6px;
    /*margin-top: 10px;*/
}
.right
{
    text-align: right;  margin-right: 4px;
}
.teacher
{
    margin-left: 4px;
}
td{
  height:130px;
  width:120px;
}

:root {
  --border-strong: 3px solid #777;
  --border-normal: 1px solid gray;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

table>caption {
  font-size: 6mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 1mm;
}


/* 210 x 297 mm */

table {
  width: 297mm;
  height: 210mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1mm;
  border: var(--border-normal);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.1mm;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

tbody tr> :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* top header */

.top_head>th {
  width: 54mm;
  height: 10mm;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top_head :first-child {
  width: 27mm;
  border: var(--border-strong);
}

.top_head :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* left header */

tbody th {
  border-left: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody>tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}


/* row */

tbody td>div {
  height: 34mm;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertical_span_all {
  font-size: 5mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

.vertical_span_all div {
  height: 10mm;
}


/* td contents */

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1mm;
  left: 1mm;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1mm;
  bottom: 1mm;
}

.teacher {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1mm;
  bottom: 1mm;
}

.note {
  font-size: 3mm;
}

.note :last-child {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 5mm;
}

  </style>
</header>
<body>
<!-- Heading -->
    <h1 class="center">{{name}}</h1>

<!-- Table -->
    <table>

<!-- Day/Periods -->
        <tr class = "top_head">
      <th scope="col">Day/Period</th>
      <th scope="col">I</th>
      <th scope="col">II</th>
      <th scope="col">III</th>
      <th scope="col">1:15-1:45</th>
      <th scope="col">IV</th>
      <th scope="col">V</th>

        </tr>
        <tbody>
<!-- Monday -->
        <tr>
        <th scope="row" class = "center">
                <b>Monday</b>
            </th>
            
            {% for course in monday %}
                {% if loop.index == 4 %}
                    <td rowspan="6" class="vertical_span_all">
                        <div>L</div>
                        <div>U</div>
                        <div>N</div>
                        <div>C</div>
                        <div>H</div>
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        <div>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                  </div>
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
<!-- Tuesday -->
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class = "center">
                <b>Tuesday</b>
            </th>
            
            {% for course in tuesday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        <div>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}
                      </div>    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
<!-- Wednesday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Wednesday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in wednesday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
<!-- Thursday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Thursday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in thursday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
<!-- Friday -->
        <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <b>Friday</b>
            </td>
            {% for course in friday %}
                {% if course[1] != 0 %}
                    <td colspan={{course[1]}}>
                        {% set count = [] %}
                        {%- for y in range(0, 5) -%}
                            {%- if count|length < course[0]|length -%}
                                <p class="left">
                            
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}
                                    </p>
                                    {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                    <p class = "right">
                                    {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                                        {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                                        {%- else -%}
                                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                            {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                                {{' '}}
                                            {%- else -%}
                                                {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                            {%- endif -%}
                                        {%- endif -%}
                                    {%- endfor -%}

                                </p>
                            {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                        <p class = "teacher">
                        {%- for z in range(count|length, course[0]|length) -%}
                            {%- if course[0][count|length] == '@' -%}
                            {%- else -%}
                                {% set __ = count.append(1) %}
                                {%- if course[0][count|length-1] == '_' -%}
                                    {{' '}}
                                {%- else -%}
                                    {{course[0][count|length-1]}}
                                {%- endif -%}
                            {%- endif -%}
                        {%- endfor -%}  
                        </p>
                        <!-- <p class="left">{{course[0]}}</p>
                        <p class="right">{{course[1]}}</p>
                        <p class="teacher">{{course[2]}}</p> -->
                       {%- endif -%}
                      {%- endfor -%}    
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>

    <p class = "new-page"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

And the python file that I am running has the following code,

```
from typing import List
import pdfkit
from pdfkit.api import configuration
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader, Environment
wkhtml_path = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = "C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")  #by using configuration you can add path value.

class section:
    def __init__(self, id, course, section, instructor, room):
        self.id = id
        self.course = course
        self.section = section
        self.instructor = instructor
        self.room = room

def generate_data():
    data = {}

    # For CS-1A
    data["CS-1A"] = [["" for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
    data["CS-1A"][0][0] += "Advance_Programming@Mr.Ashas@Room_#2 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][0] += "Applied_Physics@Bilal@Room_#1 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][1] += "Programming_Fundamentals@Muhammad_Bilal@Room_#1 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][3] += "Programming_Fundamentals_Lab@Mr._Abid@Lab_#01 "
    data["CS-1A"][0][4] += "Programming_Fundamentals_Lab@Mr._Abid@Lab_#01 "

    # You may change all these for testing purposes. 
    # data["CS-1A"][0][0].append(section(2, "Programming Fundamentals", "CS-1A", "Bilal", "Room #1"))
    # data["CS-1A"][0][1].append(section(3, "Applied Physics", "CS-1A", "Muhammad Bilal", "Room #5"))
    # obj = section(4, "Programming Lab", "CS-1A", "Mr. Abid", "Lab #01")
    # data["CS-1A"][0][1].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1A"][0][2].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1A"][0][4].append(section(5, "English Communication", "CS-1A1", "Ms. Ayeza", "Cal Lab"))
    # data["CS-1A"][0][4].append(section(6, "English Communication", "CS-1A2", "Ms. Ayesha", "GP Lab"))
    # data["CS-1A"][1][1].append(section(7, "Linear Algebra", "CS-1A", "Ms. Zain", "Romm #2"))
    # obj = section(8, "English Lab", "CS-1A", "Ms. Abida", "Lab #04")
    # data["CS-1A"][1][3].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1A"][1][4].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1A"][2][0].append(section(9, "Social Studies", "CS-1A", "Mr. Zain Iqbal", "Room #14"))
    # data["CS-1A"][2][4].append(section(10, "Programming Fundamentals", "CS-1A", "Bilal", "Room #15"))
    # # No lectures on Thursday i.e. 3rd index
    # obj = section(11, "English Lab", "CS-1A", "Ms. Abida", "Lab #03")
    # data["CS-1A"][4][1].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1A"][4][2].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1A"][4][2].append(section(12, "English Communication", "CS-1A1", "Ms. Ayeza", "Room #3"))
    # data["CS-1A"][4][2].append(section(13, "English Communication", "CS-1A2", "Ms. Ayesha", "GP Lab"))
    #
    #
    #
    # # For CS-1B
    # data["CS-1B"] = [[[] for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
    #
    # data["CS-1B"][0][1].append(section(14, "Advance Programming", "CS-1B", "Mr. Ali Hassan", "Room #2"))
    # data["CS-1B"][0][2].append(section(15, "English Comprehension and Communication", "CS-1B", "Mr. Bilal", "Room #1"))
    # obj = section(15, "Software for Mobile and Devices", "CS-1B", "Mr. Jacob", "Room #5")
    # data["CS-1B"][1][1].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1B"][1][2].append(obj)
    # data["CS-1B"][1][3].append(section(17, "Calculus and Geometrical Analytics", "CS-1B", "Ms. Nomi Khan", "Room #06"))
    # data["CS-1B"][2][3].append(section(18, "Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab", "CS-1B1", "Ms. Sarah Niaz", "Lab #01"))
    # data["CS-1B"][2][3].append(section(19, "Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab", "CS-1B2", "Ms. Julia John", "Lab #06"))
    # data["CS-1B"][2][4].append(section(20, "English Comprehenseion and Communication", "Cs-1B", "Mr. Lionel Boyle", "Room #02"))
    # data["CS-1B"][3][3].append(section(21, "Programming Fundamentals", "CS-1B", "Mr. Alex Niles", "Room #3"))
    # data["CS-1B"][4][2].append(section(22, "Linear Algebra", "CS-1B", "Ms. Ayesha", "GP Lab"))

    return data

def organise_input_data(elements: List[List[str]]) -> List[list]:
    """
    Organises the input data to find double courses for easier use in templates
    """
    new_elements = []
    for day in elements:
        last_course = None
        course_list = []
        index = 0
        for course in day:
            # cleanup data
            course = course.strip().replace(" ", "<hr>")
            # check if long course (and not lunch time)
            if course != "" and course == last_course and index != 3:
                course_list.remove((course, 1))
                course_list.append((course, 2))
                course_list.append(("none", 0))
            else:
                course_list.append((course.replace(" ", "<hr>"), 1))
            last_course = course
            index += 1
        new_elements.append(course_list)

    return new_elements


def generate_html(template, name: str, elements: List[list]) -> str:

    new_elements = organise_input_data(elements=elements)

    rendered = template.render(
        name=name,
        monday=new_elements[0],
        tuesday=new_elements[1],
        wednesday=new_elements[2],
        thursday=new_elements[3],
        friday=new_elements[4]
    )

    with open(f"out_{name}.html", "w+") as file:
        file.write(rendered)

    return rendered


def run(input_data):
    # Init jinja
    file_loader = FileSystemLoader('.')
    env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
    template = env.get_template('template.html')

    full_text = ""
    for name, elements in input_data.items():
        full_text += generate_html(template=template, name=name, elements=elements)

    pdfkit.from_string(full_text, "out.pdf", configuration = wkhtml_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = generate_data()
    run(data)
```

Comment: @KJ Ok thank you! That does makes the table look much better in the borders! Although the td spacing still remains the same.

Comment: Step 1, use valid HTML. The `style` tag should be in a `head` tag. The `br` tag is slef closing so using `</br>` results in invalid html. Step 2, use appropriate tags, eg `th` where appropriate and avoid `br`

Comment: There is quite a bit going on here. Personally I would get rid of `<table border="5" cellspacing="5">` also some of your html is being parsed with spaces like `<p class = "right">Amjad Hussain</p>` a modern browser might interpret this correctly, but it looks weird in the code and I would worry it could throw issues. Can you make a jsfiddle and then perhaps other users can refine your code. Also passing in heights and widths to a table is generally not a great idea, you can use some fixed widths but this can also cause unpredictable issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are targeting print media then you need to specify absolute dimensions in mm, cm, inch. If you are printing on A4 page then your page is `210x297mm` and you need to print it in landscape mode.
For printing/pdf the page needs to be styled like this:

```css
:root {
  --border-strong: 3px solid #777;
  --border-normal: 1px solid gray;
}

body {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

table>caption {
  font-size: 6mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 1mm;
}


/* 210 x 297 mm */

table {
  width: 297mm;
  height: 210mm;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 1mm;
  border: var(--border-normal);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.1mm;
  font-weight: bold;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

tbody tr> :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* top header */

.top_head>th {
  width: 54mm;
  height: 10mm;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.top_head :first-child {
  width: 27mm;
  border: var(--border-strong);
}

.top_head :last-child {
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
}


/* left header */

tbody th {
  border-left: var(--border-strong);
  border-right: var(--border-strong);
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody>tr:last-child th {
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}


/* row */

tbody td>div {
  height: 34mm;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vertical_span_all {
  font-size: 5mm;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: var(--border-strong);
}

.vertical_span_all div {
  height: 10mm;
}


/* td contents */

.left {
  width: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1mm;
  left: 1mm;
}

.left>div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 3mm;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1mm;
  bottom: 1mm;
}

.teacher {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1mm;
  bottom: 1mm;
}

.note {
  font-size: 3mm;
}

.note :last-child {
  float: right;
}

@page {
  margin: 5mm;
}
```

```html
<!-- Table -->
<table>
  <caption>CS-1A</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr class='top_head'>
      <th scope="col">Day/Period</th>
      <th scope="col">I</th>
      <th scope="col">II</th>
      <th scope="col">III</th>
      <th scope="col">1:15-1:45</th>
      <th scope="col">IV</th>
      <th scope="col">V</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Monday -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="center">
        <b>Monday</b>
      </th>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div class="left">
          <div>Digital Logic Design</div>
          <div>Applied Physics</div>
          <div>Advanced Programming</div>
        </div>
        <p class="right">Mirza Waqar Baig</p>
        <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div class="left">
          <div>English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <div>Applied Physics</div>
        </div>
        <p class="right">Muhammad Ammar</p>
        <p class="teacher">CS-1A2</p>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="6" class="vertical_span_all">
        <div>L</div>
        <div>U</div>
        <div>N</div>
        <div>C</div>
        <div>H</div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <p class="right">Junaid Shahid</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Programming Fundamentals</div>
          <p class="right">Rizwan ul Haq</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Tuesday -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="center">
        <b>Tuesday</b>
      </th>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Programming Fundamentals</div>
          <p class="right">Rizwan ul Haq</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
          <div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="left">Programming Fundamentals - Lab</div>
            <p class="right">Mughees Ismail</p>
            <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</div>
          <p class="right">Rizwanullah</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <p class="right">Junaid Shahid</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Wednesday -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="center">
        <b>Wednesday</b>
      </th>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Digital Logic Design</div>
          <p class="right">Mirza Waqar Baig</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Digital Logic Design - Lab</div>
          <p class="right">Muhammad Arslan</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab</div>
          <p class="right">Muiz Qadir</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Thursday -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="center">
        <b>Thursday</b>
      </th>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Linear Algebra</div>
          <p class="right">Amjad Hussain</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <div>
          <div class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</div>
          <p class="right">Muhammad Iqbal</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A2</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=2>
        <div>
          <div class="left">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</div>
          <p class="right">Sadia Ashfaq</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A1</p>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Friday -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="center">
        <b>Friday</b>
      </th>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <p class="right">Muhammad Ammar</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A2</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Islamic Studies/Ethics</div>
          <p class="right">Rizwanullah</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
          <div class="left">Linear Algebra</div>
          <p class="right">Amjad Hussain</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan=1>
        <div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class='note'><span>w.e.f. Monday, September 13, 2021</span> <span>aSc Timetables</span></div>
```

This is how it looks while printing pdf:

[image]

To have multiple courses in one cell use structure like this:

```html
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="left">
            <div>Digital Logic Design</div>
            <div>Applied Physics</div>
            <div>Advanced Programming</div>
          </div>
          <p class="right">Mirza Waqar Baig</p>
          <p class="teacher">CS-1A</p>
        </td>
```

Also look at the modified style.

Comment: This is a very good answer. However, it unfortunately caused the same problem that I was facing previously. I have edited to include that problem. The reason why I went for that approach was because I had to divide the Cells if there were any overlapping courses on one slot. I tried to change things up in this current code to somehow accodomate those overalpping courses as well but nothing seemed to work for me.

Comment: Sorry, it kind of doesn't work :/ Please look at the second image I provided in the main question. You will notice that a `complete cell` is divided when there are multiple courses on one slot. For example, Monday 4th slot, you will notice two complete cells horizontally divided on that one slot (each cell will contain its own Course, Teacher and Room Number). Trying to follow the last modified code by you, I was able to divide the Course names but unfortunately, teacher and room names remain the same and we can't multiple of those for one cell.

Comment: You'll have to handle it in python code. For each extra parallel lecture create one more row for the same day. And for remaining non-parallel lectures increase the colspan by 1. And divide the row height by number of parallel lectures on that day. This can't be achieved in CSS styling alone.

Comment: Yes, I tried to resolve it using some logic. I managed to finally achieve it as well however the alignment of the cells weren't soo good. all the text was more centrally aligned except for those cells in which there was a partition between two courses. Nevertheless, thank you so much for the answer. I will try to improve it on my own further. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done here is remove the borders from the table and collapsed the space for them.

I've then used more semantic elements for both table headings and your actual content with semantic class names. This included adding a new element for the elements you want at the bottom of the cell. Finally, the teacher and codes are floated left and right respectively.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.lunch {
  text-align: center;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
}

.lunch h2 {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

/*remove borders*/
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
}

.code {
  float: right;
}

.teacher {
  float: left;
}

td,
th {
  height: 175px;
  width: 150px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
}

th:first-child {
  border-left: solid 1px black
}

thead th {
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Heading -->
  <h1 class="center">CS-1A</h1>

  <!-- Table -->
  <table>
    <!-- Day/Periods -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Day/Period</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>II</th>
        <th>III</th>
        <th>1:15-1:45</th>
        <th>IV</th>
        <th>V</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- Monday -->
      <tr>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Digital Logic Design</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Mirza Waqar Baig</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Muhammad Ammar</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A2</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="6" class="lunch">
          <h2>LUNCH</h2>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Junaid Shahid</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A1</div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Programming Fundamentals</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Rizwan ul Haq</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Tuesday -->
      <tr>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Programming Fundamentals</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Rizwan ul Haq</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="className">Programming Fundamentals - Lab</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Mughees Ismail</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Islamic Studies/Ethics</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Rizwanullah</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Junaid Shahid</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A1</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Wednesday -->
      <tr>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Digital Logic Design</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Mirza Waqar Baig</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="className">Digital Logic Design - Lab</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Muhammad Arslan</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="className">Introduction to Information and Communication Technology - Lab</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Muiz Qadir</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Thursday -->
      <tr>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Linear Algebra</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Amjad Hussain</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="className">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Muhammad Iqbal</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A2</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="className">English Composition and Comprehension - Lab</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Sadia Ashfaq</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A1</div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Friday -->
      <tr>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">English Composition and Comprehension</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Muhammad Ammar</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A2</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Islamic Studies/Ethics</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Rizwanullah</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
          <div class="className">Linear Algebra</div>
          <div class="footer">
            <div class="teacher">Amjad Hussain</div>
            <div class="code">CS-1A</div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan=1>
        </td>
      </tr>

  </table>
</body>
```