# Objects of type 'WindowsPath' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT

Tags: python, pdf, xlsx, win32com

I have an xlsx file which is a template for a receipt. It contains images and cells. I used to go into the file manually, update the information and then export to pdf before sending to my clients. I would like to be able to convert an xlsx to pdf through python if possible.

My problem is no one shows a tutorial which just chooses a xlsx file and changes it to pdf. Or no decent video tutorial.

I've tried getting openpyxl to save it as an extension with .pdf but i know that was a long shot. And i tried to follow an example on stack overflow but it didnt work that well.

> I keep getting :
>
> ```
> File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 5, in ExportAsFixedFormat 
> Objects of type 'WindowsPath' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT
> ```

and I'm pretty stuck.

```
#this file will open a wb and save it as another file name
#this first part opens a file from a location and makes a copy to another location

from pathlib import Path
from win32com import client

#sets filename and file
file_name = 'After Summer Bookings.xlsx'
dir_path = Path('C:/Users/BOTTL/Desktop/Business')
new_file_name = 'hello.pdf'
new_save_place = Path('C:/Users/BOTTL/Desktop/Business Python')

xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dir_path / file_name)
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, new_save_place / new_file_name)
```

I'd like it to open the xlsx file I have called `After Summer Bookings.xlsx` and save it as a pdf file called `hello.pdf`

Comment: "An example on SO" --> where's the link to what you tried to follow? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854840/xlsx-and-xlslatest-versions-to-pdf-using-python). The path argument of `ExportAsFixedFormat` should match this format: `ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'C:\\excel\\trial.pdf')`

Comment: Hi that's the thread I followed and the variables within my code are equal to what is above.

Comment: the code works if instead of putting a path i just put the filename (hello.pdf) . It saves it to the C:\Users\BOTTL\Documents\ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself :)

```
from pathlib import Path
from win32com import client

#sets filename and file
file_name = 'After Summer Bookings.xlsx'
dir_path = Path('C:/Users/BOTTL/Desktop/Business')
new_file_name = 'hello.pdf'
new_save_place = ('C:/Users/BOTTL/Desktop/Business Python/')
path_and_place = new_save_place + new_file_name

xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(dir_path / file_name)
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0,path_and_place)
```

when concatenating the location and the filename it didn't like that I had made it a path, so now that I removed path, it works like a dream :)

Comment: will do in 2 days: it appears i cannot before then