# Python Converting an Excel file (.xlsx) to a PDF (.pdf)

Tags: python, excel

I'd like to transform an excel (.xlsx) file to a .pdf file.  I found this code:

```
from win32com import client
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\gregd\\PycharmProjects\\excel\\data.xlsx')
ws = books.Worksheets[0]
ws.Visible = 1
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'C:\\Users\\gregd\\PycharmProjects\\excel\\data.pdf')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/gregd/PycharmProjects/excel/idea.py", line 3, in <module>
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\gregd\\PycharmProjects\\excel\\data.xlsx')
File "C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\excel\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 
527, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

The code seems to work for others, but not for me. Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 0):

I just consulted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20867193/10231266) from which you copied this code fragment and simply deduced that this method only opens documents with xls extensions (not xlsx).

Here's [a useful link](https://www.aconvert.com/document/xlsx-to-xls/) that might help you to convert your file(s) to xls format.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API available which converts the .xlsx file to .pdf file.

**Reference:** https://www.convertapi.com/xlsx-to-pdf