# Golang packages for doc to docx and docx to pdf convertion?

Tags: go

I am writing a web application in Golang, in which user can upload a doc or docx file. Some of the file contents will be changed according to a predefined format. Later user can download the changed file either in docx or in pdf format. Now my application accepts only docx file, change the file according to predefined format and let the user download it back in docx format itself. Are there any packages available in golang to convert doc to docx and docx to pdf?

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: @codefreak I am using Linux.

Comment: You can use a linux cmd utility for doc 2 pdf see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203626/is-there-any-gnu-linux-command-line-utility-that-converts-docx-files-to-pdf. Once installed and working, you can call that utility by executing os.Exec function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am using linux ubuntu OS Hugo's answer didn't help me(But I recommend it for the windows users). But it gave me an idea about how to solve this problem. codefreak's comment on the question gave me a clear picture. I used both of their advice and result was the use of LibreOffice for the convertion.

```
arg0 := "lowriter"
arg1 := "--invisible" //This command is optional, it will help to disable the splash screen of LibreOffice.
arg2 := "--convert-to"
arg3 := "pdf:writer_pdf_Export"
path := "/home/user/Test.docx"
nout, err := exec.Command(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,path).Output()
```

This code will call LibreOffice and convert .docx file into .pdf. This is the easiest method as far as I know. Please post other answers which may help future readers.

Comment: If you are not using Libreoffice then arg0 may change accordingly. For example, **oowriter** or **sowriter** for OpenOffice. Check **oowriter --help** in terminal for the invisibility command(Not sure about others having one.).

Comment: For arg0, I am using "soffice", also, you may need to add arg4 and arg5 of "--outdir" in case you need to save file in other position.

Comment: On Fedora 31 it was `libreoffice` instead of lowriter

Answer (score 2):

This will work over windows, as it is using the windows functions

https://github.com/piaobocpp/doc2pdf-go

Comment: Thanks. But I am using Linux. Any other options?