# Python Visio to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, visio, comtypes

I'm trying to convert a bunch of Visio files to pdf in python. I have referenced this [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python) and written the following code:

```
import comtypes.client as coms

format=17    
visio = coms.CreateObject('Visio.Application')
doc = visio.Documents.Open('map.vsd')
doc.SaveAs('map.pdf', FileFormat=format)
```

gives me a `TypeError: call takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

I've been Googling and can't find the reference on how to print to pdf in Visio using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ExportAsFixedFormat` instead `SaveAs`. Documentation for this function you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms409271%28v=office.12%29.aspx). This function can be used with a win32 and a comtypes.

**win32com example**

```
import win32com.client
visio = win32com.client.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
doc = visio.Documents.Open('map.vsd')
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat( 1, 'map.pdf', 1, 0 )
```

**comtypes example**

```
import comtypes.client as coms
visio = coms.CreateObject('Visio.Application')
doc = visio.Documents.Open('map.vsd')
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat( 1, 'map.pdf', 1, 0 )
```

Comment: Is there any update to this with the .vsdx format and Visio 2016? I am getting an error when running this code with that file format. Specifically, I get "(-2032466859, None, ('\n\nThis file name is not valid.', 'Visio Professional', None, 0, None))".

Comment: I am getting this error - `Arguments: (com_error(-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None),)`