# Pywin32 save .docx as pdf

Tags: python, pywin32, word-2013

I'm using Word 2013 to automatically create a report as a docx and then save it as a pdf format.

But when I call the function SaveAs2(), the script pop out the "save as" windows and throws this exception :

```
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Word', u'Command failed', u'wdmain11.chm', 36966, -2146824090), None)
```

Here is my code to open and to save as a new file:

```
self.path = os.path.abspath(path)

self.wordApp = win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')  #create a word application object
self.wordApp.Visible = False  # if false hide the word application (app does't open but still usable)

self.document = self.wordApp.Documents.Open(self.path + "/" + documentRef)  # opening the template file



absFileName = "D:\\test.pdf"
        self.document.SaveAs2(FileName=absFileName,FileFormat=17)
```

And I'm using : 
python2.7 with pywin32 (build 219)

Does someone had an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Why not just create the report using reportlab? Then it's all in Python and you don't have to worry about these conversion issues.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of nice libraries to handle this task:

- [python-docx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-docx)
- [xtopdf](https://bitbucket.org/vasudevram/xtopdf)

There is also an example of doing [exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481136/pywin32-save-docx-as-pdf) in this ActiveState Recipe [Convert Microsoft Word files to PDF with DOCXtoPDF](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578795-convert-microsoft-word-files-to-pdf-with-docxtopdf/)

---

If you *insist* on using Windows API(s) there is also an example of doing this via `win32com` in this recipe [Convert doc and docx files to pdf](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578858-convert-doc-and-docx-files-to-pdf/)

---

You *could* also do this using [`comtypes`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes) (*Thanks to [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)*)

**Example:**

```
import os
import sys


import comtypes.client


wdFormatPDF = 17


def covx_to_pdf(infile, outfile):
    """Convert a Word .docx to PDF"""

    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(infile)
    doc.SaveAs(outfile, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
```

Comment: Hi James and thanks for your answer and your suggestion! I have tried your examples with comtypes and ActiveState but unfortunately, it creates the same trouble as above during the save part.
As for python-docx, it doesn’t allow to save it as an pdf [document]( https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/113) and all the other library doesn’t seem to take the docx header.

Comment: James, the python-docx library is great (already using it) but cannot be used to generate the PDF. You need a "renderer" to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the "Office 2013" is the bottleneck.

I have the same issue while using Word 2013 ("Office 2013"),
but when I try to run your code snippet with "Office 365" and "Office 2010", **it works**.

**I can recommend two solutions for now:**

- try out different MS Office versions (365 and 2010 tested)
- use some online API-s to convert it to PDF

**Note:**
Changing the module/library won't fix the issue,
only the right Office version will.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, don't forget to install win32 like this:

```
pip install pywin32
```

the function to convert doc to pdf is like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32  
def convert_to_pdf(doc):
    """Convert given word document to pdf"""
    word = win32.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
    new_name = doc.replace(".docx", r".pdf")
    worddoc = word.Documents.Open(doc)
    worddoc.SaveAs(new_name, FileFormat=17)
    worddoc.Close()
    return None

path_to_word_document = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'report_1.docx')
convert_to_pdf(path_to_word_document)
```

give me my starts, i really need it :-)
for more look for the documentation in the library
https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/