# Batch convert over 1500 files to docx to png or pdf

Tags: python, pdf, parallel-processing, docx, file-conversion

I am using Mac OS 10.12

I am needing to batch convert between 1500-2000 files to png/pdf from docx.

I have tried pandoc but that loses file format and font, which is imperative to the task. I could parallelize this but without the results I require.

I have tried soffice, but that takes ~6-8 seconds per run, and spawns a new libreoffice software process with each run. The latter part has prevented parallelization of soffice.

Is there any way I could process this many files while maintaining font and format to pdf or png?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using windows/mac/linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30481136/198633

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I am using mac. It's been edited

Comment: Take a look at this: http://lifehacker.com/quickly-convert-docx-files-to-pdf-with-an-automator-act-1764798762

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Unfortunately, the bash script he uses to create the right-click tool, first converts to HTML removing font and format

Comment: How about this: https://onabai.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/convert-word-files-docdocx-to-pdf-in-osx/

Comment: @inspectorG4dget This does not appear to work on my Version of Mac, or Word. I get Word opened, but no conversion. Also this launches Word on every run. This wouldn't be feasible with the number of files I am converting. This is more similar to the soffice option

Comment: are you able to run a windows virtual machine to use python and win32com?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I am on work hardware and am unable to install or use a virtual machine