# python - print preview of a document

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to have print preview of  a document base on a form created on tkinter? If possible, can I print it to frame?

I'm planning to use python-docs to convert the .docx file to a pdf then convert the pdf to image and view it on a tkinter frame using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)

Is there any easier way?

Comment: Printing in general not a trivial task in Python (unfortunately, no crossplatform solution), and so and print preview. AFAIK, there's no easier way with tkinter, except your. But [`Qt`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprintpreviewdialog.html) and [`wx`](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Printing) frameworks can into a print preview dialog right from a box!

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try wx and qt later.