# Trying to convert excel sheets to PDF using Python but throwing up this error

Tags: python, excel, windows, pdf

Hi I am trying to convert excel sheet to pdf using python, converted a script wrote to do same with word documents, which works fine but having this error below flagging up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alank/Python training/Exceltopdf2.py", line 13, in <module>
    xlxs.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=xlxsFormatPDF)
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

any help appreciated and script is below

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

xlxsFormatPDF = 17

in_file = (r'C:\Users\alank\Python training\Helloworld.xlsx')
out_file = (r'C:\Users\alank\Python training\Helloworld.pdf')


excel = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Excel.Application')
xlxs = excel.workbooks.Open(in_file)
xlxs.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=xlxsFormatPDF)
xlxs.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [`win32com.client`](https://www.zacoding.com/en/post/python-excel-to-pdf/#:~:text=To%20convert%20an%20Excel%20file,following%20is%20a%20sample%20program.&text=All%2012%20sheets%20are%20specified,output%20PDF%20is%20as%20follows.)
like this:

```
import win32com.client
from pywintypes import com_error


WB_PATH =   r'C:\Users\alank\Python training\Helloworld.xlsx'

PATH_TO_PDF = r'C:\Users\alank\Python training\Helloworld.pdf'


excel.Visible = False
try:
    # Open
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH)

    # Specify the sheet you want to save by index. 
    #if you want all the sheets in excel try with: 
    #wb.WorkSheets(wb.Sheets.Count) or wb.WorkSheets([i=1 for i in range(wb.Sheets.Count)]).Select() 
    ws_index_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

    # Save
    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, PATH_TO_PDF)
except com_error as e:
    print('The convertion failed.')
else:
    print('Succeessful convertion')
finally:
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
```

Or you can do it like [here (Andreas solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448316/13676202):

```
import os
import comtypes.client

SOURCE_DIR = r'C:\Users\alank\Python training'
TARGET_DIR = r'C:\Users\alank\Python training'

app = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Excel.Application')
app.Visible = False

infile = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(SOURCE_DIR), 'Helloworld.xlsx')
outfile = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(TARGET_DIR), 'Helloworld.pdf')

doc = app.Workbooks.Open(infile)
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, outfile, 1, 0)
doc.Close()

app.Quit()
```