# No module named client, converting docx to pdf

Tags: python, docx, comtypes

I am using Python 2.7.14.

I am currently working on a program that makes adjustments to certain information on a word document. This goal has been achieved however I am facing troubles converting the .docx document into a .pdf.

I would like to use the code in this link: [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)

However I am getting an error when importing `comtypes.client`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\comtypes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetActiveObject
  File "C:\Python27\comtypes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from comtypes.client import CreateObject, GetActiveObject
ImportError: No module named client
```

It does look like I have installed comtypes using  `pip install comtypes`.

This is the code I would like to use to convert my docx into pdf and also where I am encountering an error.

Appreciate any advice.

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Comment: Can you check again with `pip install comtypes` to verify you have installed it?

Comment: What is inside that comtypes.py? It does not look like what you need at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use pycharm as an ide.
It will install your package by just a right clicking.
Or use

```
pip install comtypes
```