# Convert Microsoft Word document to PDF using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ms-word

I have tons of Word and Excel files. I want to convert many Word files in folders by sub folders to PDF, and I try following code.

This code is not active (I mean there aren't Word convert to PDF) although no error.

[image]

What could be the problem? Is there another solution?

This is my code:

```
import os
from win32com import client
path = 'D:\programing\test'
word_file_names = []
word = client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print (dirpath)
    for f in filenames:
        if f.lower().endswith(".docx") and re.search('Addendum', f):
            new_name = f.replace(".docx", r".pdf")
            in_file = word_file_names.append(dirpath + "\\" + f)
            new_file = word_file_names.append(dirpath + "\\" + new_name)
            doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat = 17)
            doc.Close()
        if f.lower().endswith(".doc") and re.search('Addendum', f):
            new_name = f.replace(".doc", r".pdf")
            in_file = word_file_names.append(dirpath + "\\" + f)
            new_file = word_file_names.append(dirpath + "\\" + new_name)
            doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat = 17)
            doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
```

Comment: This question has been answered before and this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python

Comment: Is there any output at all? Can you show the stuff being printed? Have you tried running this in a debugger?

Comment: i  have added the  the result photo in my tobic

Comment: You have commented out the `except` block, are you sure the code is not throwing any error?

Comment: ok ankit , i have summarized my code for important thing only (look agin), if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem and fixed the code has following

```
import os
import win32com.client
import re
path = (r'D:\programing\test')
word_file_names = []
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for f in filenames:  
        if f.lower().endswith(".docx") :
            new_name = f.replace(".docx", ".pdf")
            in_file =(dirpath + '/'+ f)
            new_file =(dirpath + '/' + new_name)
            doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat = 17)
            doc.Close()
        if f.lower().endswith(".doc"):
            new_name = f.replace(".doc", ".pdf")
            in_file =(dirpath +'/' + f)
            new_file =(dirpath +'/' + new_name)
            doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
            doc.SaveAs(new_file, FileFormat = 17)
            doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is way easier:

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert(word_path, pdf_path)
```

Comment: ps, this needs microsoft word to be installed to work. otherwise, was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: You can use 'convert(Output_folder)' to convert all word files in a folder

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to export with Bookmarks? This is an option when exporting from Word, but not sure if this option exists within win32.

Answer (score 1):

You can use comtypes,

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
import os

folder = "folder path"
wdToPDF = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdFormatPDF = 17
files = os.listdir(folder)
word_files = [f for f in files if f.endswith((".doc", ".docx"))]
for word_file in word_files:
    word_path = os.path.join(folder, word_file)
    pdf_path = word_path
    if pdf_path[-3:] != 'pdf':
        pdf_path = pdf_path + ".pdf"

    if os.path.exists(pdf_path):
        os.remove(pdf_path)

    pdfCreate = wdToPDF.Documents.Open(word_path)
    pdfCreate.SaveAs(pdf_path, wdFormatPDF)
```