# Converting DOCX file to PDF from command line

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, docx

I am writing a python script and would like to convert a DOCX to PDF.  Are there any ways of doing this?  Here's my current code:

```
printer_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Nitro\\Pro\\12\\NitroPDF.exe'
doc_path = 'Test.docx'

subprocess.call([printer_path,  doc_source_path])
```

Nitro PDF will open and begin converting the file but won't finish.  Thank you for any input.

Edit 1: For the subprocess.call to work, I had to make both inputs absolute paths e.g. doc_path = 'C:\Documents\Test.docx'

Comment: Does this work fine if you do it manually instead of programmatically?

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)?

Comment: @jwalton3141 That answer was exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Microsoft Word installed the following should work:

```
subprocess.call('docto -f "C:\Dir with Spaces\FilesToConvert\" -O "C:\DirToOutput" -T wdFormatPDF  -OX .pdf', shell=True)
```

Comment: You will also need DocTo installed https://github.com/tobya/docto

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `docx2pdf` python package to convert docx with zero formatting issues on Windows or macOS. It requires Microsoft Word to be installed and uses the COM API on Windows and AppleScript (JXA) on macOS.

```py
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("input.docx")
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
convert("my_docx_folder/")
```

Disclaimer: I wrote docx2pdf. https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf

Comment: docx2pdf is not implemented for linux as it requires Microsoft Word to be installed

Comment: @PHZ.fi-Pharazon that's right! Although I heard some reports that it seems to be compatible with "WPS Office" (https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf/pull/10) but I haven't tried it myself.