# how to convert word file into pdf using python?

Tags: python, python-docx

I tried using pypdf2 but it is not working.

```
import docx 
from docx2pdf import convert
doc = docx.Document()
tr_no = "TR9K939393r4"
doc.add_paragraph(tr_no)
doc.save("E:\Test.docx")

convert("E:\Test.docx")
convert("E:\Test.docx", "E:\Test.pdf")
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Have you tried putting the files in the same folder as the script, and just refering to them by filename, to avoid any potential issue with filepaths not working?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54795515/converting-docx-file-to-pdf-from-command-line

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Try using: **docx2pdf** module

```
from docx2pdf import convert

    convert("input.docx")
    convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
    convert("my_docx_folder/")
```

Works fine for me.