# Django Doc Convert to HTML

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am looking for a HTML converter which allows me to convert .doc to HTML in my Django project.
In my project, .docx files can be converted but not .doc files.
     .docx file processing was done as follows.
**view.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def fileload(request):
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
    urls = settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'fileload/'
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location=urls, base_url=urls)
    filename = fs.save(file.name, file)
    filepath = urls + file.name
    ext = os.path.splitext(filepath)[1]
    print(ext)
    html=None
    code = '0'
    if ext == '.docx':
       html = get_docx_html(filepath)
       code = '1'
    fs.delete(file.name)
       data = {
           'code': code,
           'html': html
       }
     response = JsonResponse(data)

     return response

def get_docx_html(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as docx_file:
        result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
        html = result.value  
        messages = result.messages  

    return html
```

In the same way, doc files are not converted.
I'd like to have the .doc file converted.
Any idea of approach that can be recommended or sample code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is a doc file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)

Comment: This is not a window. This is Linux.