# .doc to pdf using python errors

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert word documents to PDF using python.Currently on python 3.8.

"[.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)"

```
import sys                                                                                                   
import os                                                                                                 
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])                  
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')             
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)                 
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)          
doc.Close()          
word.Quit()
```

above code answers my question but it works only on my machine when I deploy it onto VM and run it using scheduler remotely, I get below error

```
File "File Name", line 10, in <module>                                   
word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
File "Path", init__.py",line1225, in CoCreateInstance
----------------------------------------------------
File"_ctypes/callproc.c",line 930, in getResult
PermissionError:[WinError -2147024891] Access is denied
```

FYI, word is installed on VM

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)

Comment: No, as mentioned I used same code but getting error mentioned in post.