# pywintypes.com_error saving word doc as pdf python pywin32

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32, file-conversion

I am opening a word document in word using python and trying to convert it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6018039/12586050) answer on StackOverflow.

My python code:

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
wdFormatPDF = 17
doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
doc.SaveAs(file_name, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

However, when doing so, I am met with this error:

```
doc.SaveAs(file_name, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
  File "<COMObject Open>", line 5, in SaveAs
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'wdmain11.chm', 36966, -2146824090), None)
```

Please can you explain what this error means and how to fix my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. In my case, I did not have write permissions in the directory I was saving to.

See also: [Error pywintypes.com_error occur when convert files docx to files pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65300178/error-pywintypes-com-error-occur-when-convert-files-docx-to-files-pdf)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32169234)

Comment: My answer is the first line I wrote and is different from the answer provided by the link. I added the link to supplement my answer with another possibility. Maybe the link should be deleted?