# Convert the docx file into pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, exe, docx, python-docx

I am workin on a report generator, and I used `pip install python-docx` and
`import docx`.
Now I have made a new docx file, edited it but I want to save it in pdf instead of docx file. And the program script will be converted into `EXE` file.
Please help.

```
(pip install python-docx)

from docx import Document

doc=Document()

doc.add_heading('Report', 0)

# Now to save file, I know to save in docx,
# But, I want to save in pdf
# I can not finish the program and then manually convert
# As this script will run as an 
# **EXE**    

doc.save('report.docx')
```

I tried saving like -->  `doc.save('report.pdf')` But, it did not work.

Comment: If the end result is going to be a PDF, then why go through the DOCX phase at all?  There are several excellent PDF libraries for Python that will allow to create a PDF directly, with full and complete control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python package [docx2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/)*:

```
pip install docx2pdf
```

Then call the convert function:
`convert("report.docx", "report.pdf")` after saving `doc.save('report.docx')`. Creating the docx file before converting it is mandatory.

- unless you work on a Linux Machine as it requires Microsoft Word to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the msoffice2pdf library using Microsoft Office or LibreOffice installed in the environment.

https://pypi.org/project/msoffice2pdf/

Comment: In Linux (Ubuntu) doesn't work.