# Python docx2pdf AttributeError: Open.SaveAs

Tags: python, docx, pywin32, python-docx, comtypes

I am trying to convert a docx file to pdf using the docx2pdf library, using the following code:

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert("generated.docx")
```

As written [here](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/). But I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\script.py", line 29, in <module>
    convert("generated.docx")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx2pdf-0.1.8-py3.10.egg\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 106, in convert
    return windows(paths, keep_active)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx2pdf-0.1.8-py3.10.egg\docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 33, in windows
    doc.SaveAs(str(pdf_filepath), FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Open.SaveAs
```

I also tried converting with **comtypes** and **pywin32**, but I get the same error. I take code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python).

```
import sys
import comtypes.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath("generated.docx")
out_file = os.path.abspath("generated.pdf")

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
---------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\script.py", line 45, in <module>
    doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

```
import sys
import win32com.client

wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath("generated.docx")
out_file = os.path.abspath("generated.pdf")

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
---------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\script.py", line 46, in <module>
    doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Open.SaveAs
```

How can I fix this error? Or please suggest another way to convert docx to pdf. Thank you in advance

Comment: For the last version, maybe try `word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')` instead? It seems as if all the versions are getting confused with the type library.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
```

to

```
import pythoncom
word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application', pythoncom.CoInitialize())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from docx2pdf import convert

inputFile = "document.docx"
outputFile = "document2.pdf"
file = open(outputFile, "w")
file.close()

convert(inputFile, outputFile)
```

You should create the output file first

Comment: It still doesn't work. The error does not change. I tried creating a real pdf, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

One of the observations I had is that this issue happens when the Word document is opened in Microsoft Word and then we try to execute `convert()` for the same Word file.

If that is the case, if the file is opened, please close it first and try again.