# How can I implement a word to PDF conversion in python without importing any libraries?

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, converters

First time poster here. I'm trying to convert one or multiple .docx files to PDF but I can't figure out how to do it without importing any libraries/modules aside from what is available in python 3.3.

I've read through the packages documentation but nothing stuck out as a solution. I also don't know what I am looking for as I am pretty new to python. I found plenty of articles and resources that mention how to do it with an imported library, but not without.

Is it possible to accomplish this without importing a library?

Any advice/resources are welcome.

Comment: Why would you want to do it without importing any libraries? Just curious.

Comment: It's a scenario that I would like to avoid because it would slow down the delivery.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python writing own converter won't be faster, python is strong with libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code it from scratch. If you're not going to use an external library, that is *by* *definition* pretty much your only option.

You'll want to become an expert in the formal specifications for both [PDF](https://www.pdfa.org/resource/pdf-specification-index/)
and [MS Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-doc/ccd7b486-7881-484c-a137-51170af7cc22).  Given the complexity and history of each of those, I expect a senior developer will want 6-12 months of experience with each to obtain the necessary understanding.

You should also have 6-12 months' experience with Python, since you'll likely need to be familiar with the language in order to define and use all the functions you'll need.  But in just a few years of dedication, you should be able to write the necessary code.

MORE REALISTICALLY, import Python libraries for managing [PDFs](https://github.com/pikepdf/pikepdf) and [MS Word](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  That should only take a week or two.